# Is Padre Pio known to have sworn, at least rarely?

Tags: catholicism, saint

In [this clip "Shia LaBeouf in Padre Pio (2022) "Say Christ is Lord!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDBUSmQ4B_8), Shia LeBeouf, portraying the titular Pio, delivers the line "Shut the f*ck up!"

I can't find much information on the Saint that mentions swearing at all. The closest is [this site](https://www.padrepio.catholicwebservices.com/ENGLISH/Confess.htm) which quotes him as saying "Say to your husband not to curse anymore, otherwise the demon will return." But there is no citation for this quote. But if it were a true quote it would seem to suggest Padre Pio would have refrained from swearing as much as possible.

Are there accounts of Padre Pio's life that would show this brief scene is accurate?

Comment: Having read several biographies on Padre Pio, I have never had this come up in his life. One of the major objections to his canonization was his giving communion to a “Buddhist monk” who was seemingly a non-Christian, to all but Padre Pio. Dressed as a Buddhist monk from Tibet, this individual was in reality a practicing Catholic in hiding.

Comment: @KenGraham Which biography would you recommend?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I will get back to you in time.

Comment: Maybe that clip is evil Padre Pio being tempted in a dream?

Answer (score 2):

**Is Padre Pio known to have sworn, at least rarely?**

I believe the answer to be in the negative: **no**.

St. Padre Pio is not known to have sworn in the least. From his earliest childhood, he was known to have imitated the virtue and life of Jesus Christ.

Having been born into a very humble family, [Padre Pio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_Pio) was even born in a stable, just like Our Lord at Bethlehem. He wore the marks of Jesus’ crucifixion since 1910!

I have read several biographies on Padre Pio and not one mentioned him swearing or using foul language in one way or another.

Swearing like a sailor, would have hindered his canonization big time.